# Link to subdirectories

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to link to each subdirectory and csv file in each.
The setup is:

```
2017
    - file1.csv
    - file2.csv
2016
    -file3.csv
etc...
```

I am using php as follows:

***EDITS****
I appreciate the response below and I adapted it slightly to provide the correct link. However, when I click the directory for year, '2013', it is denied. It links as `'/DeskTracker/Circulation_Files//2013'`. I am trying to fix this, but if anyone has a suggestion it is appreciated.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Circulation Files </title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="DeskTracker.html"> Home </a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
function listFolderFiles($root, $path = ''){
    $ffs = scandir($root . $path);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        echo '<li><a href="Circulation_Files/'.$path.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'';
        if(is_dir($root.$path.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($root, $path.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

listFolderFiles('//iis-demo/inetpub/GA/DeskTracker/Circulation_Files/');
?>
```

The directories and files list out perfectly, but when I click a link it does not download the file. It instead takes me to an error page with the address as:

```
http://Path/To/File/Circulation_Files/2013-August26-December20.csv
```

The path should be:

```
http://Path/To/File/Circulation_Files/2013/2013-August26-December20.csv
```

As the csv file is found within the 2013 directory. But, I am having trouble including that directory in the link.

It does not seem to list the parent directory of the csv, such as the directory "2013" then list the csv file within it.

Comment: What is it that you want to happen when you click the folder name? Your code is creating a link to that folder - is that not what you want to do? If it is, then you need to allow directory listing, or add an index page so it has something to show when you go to it.

Comment: It's not correctly linking to the folder. For example, if I want to link to the folder '2013' the link it produces is wrong, such as http://example.com//2013 instead of http://example.com/2013.

Comment: A double slash  (`//`) generally doesn't prevent a link from working.... if you manually remove the second `/` from your browsers location bar, does it work then?

Comment: You're right, that's not the issue apparently. I suppose what I did want to happen is if the link is created for each folder ('2013', '2014', ...) then that link would open to just the file contents of that folder. Although, that might require another page for each folder year.

Comment: Yes, you would need a page in each folder to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a second argument here, that would get swapped when the function is invoked recursively. Something like

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($root, $path = ''){
    $ffs = scandir($root . $path);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        echo '<li><a href="Circulation_Files/'.$path.$ff.'">'.$ff.'';
        if(is_dir($root.$path.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($root, $path.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

listFolderFiles('//iis-demo/inetpub/GA/DeskTracker/Circulation_Files/');
?>
```